# ios: Malloc in instruments

Tags: ios

For an iOS 5 project when I do profiling using Leaks instruments. I do not see any leaks but seeing a variety of Malloc 1.00KB Malloc 10 kb etc. Corresponding to these I can see varying number of live bytes. Does Malloc represents object allocation? If I am seeing live bytes then does it means that the respective allocated memory is not returned back to iOS? How we can reduce these [if possible]. When I view the details corresponding to these Malloc then I see mostly system related entries like ft_mem_alloc.

Thanks
arnie